# How to set javascript variable from a C# variable in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How to set a C# variable to JavaScript array variable which is array.
Following `choices` is array variable.`m_lines` is c# array variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
                 term = term.toLowerCase();
                 var choices = [];
                  choices = '<%= m_lines %>';
                 //var choices = ['aaaab', 'ActionScript', 'AppleScript', 'Asp', 'Assembly', 'BASIC', 'Batch', 'C', 'C++', 'CSS', 'Clojure', 'COBOL', 'ColdFusion', 'Erlang', 'Fortran', 'Groovy', 'Haskell', 'HTML', 'Java', 'JavaScript', 'Lisp', 'Perl', 'PHP', 'PowerShell', 'Python', 'Ruby', 'Scala', 'Scheme', 'SQL', 'TeX', 'XML'];
    });
</script>
```

My actual requirement is to read a large text file (size approx 3 MB) and assign it to a JavaScript array variable. I'm not able to read file from client side and assign it to JavaScript variable, so reading at server side and trying it to assign to client side variable.
each line of file is being used as array item.

Comment: What does this *currently* produce?  What is `m_lines`?

Comment: @David m_lines is c# array variable.

Comment: Considering your requirement is to consume 3 MB of data on the client I would fetch the array using `$.ajax`...

Comment: @maxbeaudoin but how?

Comment: Not sure if you are using ASP.NET MVC, if that is the case, the way to assign C# variable to a javascript variable is -> var jsVariableName = @(CSharpVariableName);

Comment: @NandaKumarChintam its asp.net webform application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment on the question, you define `m_lines` as an array.  One approach here could be to simply serialize that array to JSON:

```
choices = <%= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m_lines) %>;
```

This is of course using [the Newtonsoft JSON.NET library](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm).  You might also be able to use `JavaScriptSerializer` (in `System.Web.Script.Serialization`) otherwise.

Comment: how to use JsonConvert on client side? it gives error JsonConvert does not exist in current context

Comment: @viveknuna: You don't use it client-side, you use it server-side.  Which is specifically what you asked for and demonstrated in the question.  I'm not sure about ways to include namespaces in Web Forms view code, but you can always reference the full namespace explicitly: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m_lines)`  Naturally you would need a reference to that library to use it at all of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
var choices = <% if (m_lines!= null) {Response.Write(m_lines.ToString());}%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the script from your example, this could be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    term = term.toLowerCase();
    var choices = [];
    choices = <%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(m_lines)  %>;
    //var choices = ['aaaab', 'ActionScript', 'AppleScript', 'Asp', 'Assembly', 'BASIC', 'Batch', 'C', 'C++', 'CSS', 'Clojure', 'COBOL', 'ColdFusion', 'Erlang', 'Fortran', 'Groovy', 'Haskell', 'HTML', 'Java', 'JavaScript', 'Lisp', 'Perl', 'PHP', 'PowerShell', 'Python', 'Ruby', 'Scala', 'Scheme', 'SQL', 'TeX', 'XML'];
});
```

Or if this is a comma separated text file and is on the client side, you could read it using javascript, something like:

```
// <input name="myfile" id="myfile" type="file" />
$("#myfile").on('change', function () {

    var file = this.files[0];
    // Some validations
    console.log(file.name);
    console.log(file.size)

    var FileReader = new window.FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        // The file's text will be in event.target.result
        //console.log(event.target.result)
        var fileContentArray = event.target.result.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g); // split by newlines

        // Use the file content in fileContentArray
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);
});
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader